# Python wrapper for Windows pipes

Tags: python, io, windows

This is done in the style of a single class, that should work like any other io-based object in Python. Help is much appreciated with anything regarding performance, documentation, or anything else.

```
import io,win32file,win32pipe, win32api
import msvcrt as ms # for fd magic
class pipe(io.IOBase):
    def __init__(self, name, pipetype = 'server', openmode = win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|win32file.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                     pipemode = win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|win32pipe.PIPE_NOWAIT,maxinstances=255,outbuffersize=1000000,inbuffersize=1000000,
                     defaulttimeout=50, securityattrib = None):
                """ An implementation of a file-like python object pipe. Documentation can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx"""
                self.pipetype = pipetype
                self.name = name
                self.openmode = openmode
                self.pipemode = pipemode
                self.__enter__ = self.connect
                if pipetype == 'server':
                    self.handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(r"\.\pipe\%s" % name,
                                                                openmode,      # default PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
                                                                pipemode,      # default PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_NOWAIT
                                                                maxinstances,  # default 255
                                                                outbuffersize, # default 1000000
                                                                inbuffersize,  # default 1000000
                                                                defaulttimeout,# default 50
                                                                securityattrib)# default None
                elif pipetype == 'client':
                    # it doesn't matter what type of pipe the server is so long as we know the name
                    self.handle = win32file.CreateFile(r"\.\pipe\%s" % name,
                              win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                              0, None,
                              win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                              0, None)
                self.fd = ms.open_osfhandle(self.handle,0)
                self.is_connected = False
                self.flags,self.outbuffersize,self.inbuffersize,self.maxinstances = win32pipe.GetNamedPipeInfo(self.handle)
    def connect(self): # TODO: WaitNamedPipe ?
        win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(self.handle,None)
        self.is_connected = True
    def __del__(self):
        print("del initiated")
        try:
            self.write(b'') # try to clear up anyone waiting
        except win32pipe.error: # no one's listening
            pass
        self.close()
    def __exit__(self):
        print("exit started")
        self.__del__()
    def isatty(self): #Return True if the stream is interactive (i.e., connected to a terminal/tty device).
        return False
    def seekable(self):
        return False
    def fileno(self):
        return self.fd
    def seek(self): # seek family
        raise IOError("Not supported")
    def tell(self): # Part of the seek family. Not supported
        raise IOError("Not supported")
    def write(self,data): # WriteFileEx impossible due to callback issues.
        if not self.is_connected and self.pipetype == 'server':
                self.connect()
        if type(data).__name__ != 'bytes': # if we don't get bytes, make it bytes
                data = bytes(data,'utf-8')
        win32file.WriteFile(self.handle,data)
        return len(data)
    def close(self):
        print("closure started")
        win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(self.handle)
    def read(self,length=None):
        if length == None:
                length=self.inbuffersize
        resp = win32file.ReadFile(self.handle,length)
        if resp[0] != 0:
            raise __builtins__.BrokenPipeError(win32api.FormatMessage(resp[0]))
        else:
            return resp[1]
```

Usage looks like this:

```
>>> server = pipe("Pipename")
>>> client = pipe("Pipename","client")
>>> client.write("hello")
>>> server.read()
b'hello'
>>> server.write("words")
>>> client.read()
b'words'
```

Comment: Your code is close to unreadable, start by making it [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant.

Comment: @JaDogg The problem with that is that I am trying to extent the io.IOBase class, and it treats these as functions and not properties. Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: I wish I could upvote @Jaime's comment more than once - you seem to have different indentation amounts at different levels and in different methods and the lines are *way* too long.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The reason why there are different indentation amounts and such is because for some reason it gave me the indentation error so I said screw this after a while and just untabified -> tabified. It looks terrible but I'd rather that it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have fixed some of the more egregious violations of [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I think the key point, more important than following any particular style, is *consistency*, which your code lacks.

I have also included some notes on implementation. Unfortunately I can't test it, as I'm using a Mac.

```
import io
import msvcrt as ms # for fd magic

import win32api, win32file, win32pipe


class pipe(io.IOBase):

    def __init__(self, name, pipetype='server',
                 openmode = (win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |
                             win32file.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED),
                 pipemode = win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | win32pipe.PIPE_NOWAIT,
                 maxinstances=255,outbuffersize=1000000,inbuffersize=1000000,
                 defaulttimeout=50, securityattrib=None):
        """ An implementation of a file-like Python object pipe.

        Documentation can be found at
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx

        """
        self.pipetype = pipetype
        self.name = name
        self.openmode = openmode
        self.pipemode = pipemode
        if pipetype == 'server':
            self.handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
                r"\.\pipe\%s" % name,
                # the defaults don't need repeating here
                openmode,
                pipemode,
                maxinstances,
                outbuffersize,
                inbuffersize,
                defaulttimeout,
                securityattrib,
            )
        elif pipetype == 'client':
            # it doesn't matter what type of pipe the server is
            # so long as we know the name
            self.handle = win32file.CreateFile(
                r"\.\pipe\%s" % name,
                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                None,
                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                None,
            )
        self.fd = ms.open_osfhandle(self.handle, 0)
        self.is_connected = False
        (self.flags, self.outbuffersize, self.inbuffersize, self.maxinstances =
         win32pipe.GetNamedPipeInfo(self.handle))

    def connect(self): # TODO: WaitNamedPipe ?
        win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(self.handle,None)
        self.is_connected = True

    # do this at class level rather than in __init__
    __enter__ = connect  

    def __del__(self):
        print("del initiated")
        try:
            self.write(b'') # try to clear up anyone waiting
        except win32pipe.error: # no one's listening
            pass
        self.close()

    def __exit__(self):
        print("exit started")
        self.__del__()

    # Use docstrings, not comments
    def isatty(self):
        """Is the stream interactive (connected to a terminal/tty)?"""
        return False

    def seekable(self):
        return False

    def fileno(self):
        return self.fd

    def seek(self):
        # I think this is clearer than an IOError
        raise NotImplementedError

    def tell(self):
        # as above
        raise NotImplementedError

    def write(self, data):
        """WriteFileEx impossible due to callback issues."""
        if not self.is_connected and self.pipetype == 'server':
            self.connect()
        # there is no need to compare the __name__ of the type!
        if not isinstance(data, bytes):
            data = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
        win32file.WriteFile(self.handle, data)
        return len(data)

    def close(self):
        print("closure started")
        win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(self.handle)

    def read(self, length=None):
        # Always compare None by identity, not equality
        if length is None:
            length = self.inbuffersize
        resp = win32file.ReadFile(self.handle, length)
        if resp[0] != 0:
            raise __builtins__.BrokenPipeError(win32api.FormatMessage(resp[0]))
        else:
            return resp[1]
```

Comment: Why did you change some of the arguments for the functions? It doesn't work without those arguments being the way that they currently are.

Comment: @williambellwisdo I don't think I did, most of the changes were to do with layout rather than functionality.

Comment: you changed the name of the pipe to r"\.pipe\%s" when it should have been r"\\.pipe\%s", as I had it. You also removed the openmode argument from the server CreateNamedPipe call.

Comment: @williambellwisdo 1. Please recheck your posted code... 2. You're right, that's a typo; as I stated, I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

### AutoPEP8

First and foremost run

```
autopep8 pipe_wrapper.py --aggressive --in-place
```

It will make the code extremely more readable adding spaces and blank lines.

### Remove debugging statements

Such as

```
print("exit started")
```

the user does not want to see the internals of your class printed.